# Initialize global variables in a package containing a compiled function

Tags: packages, compile

I have created a package that consists of a function which uses `Compile`.
This function contains a parameter, say `a`, and I want to call the package in an notebook environment and define `a` in the notebook.

So far I define this parameter within the package as `` a=Global`a `` and I call the package with `Get`.

The problem is now that I want to initialize or load the package at the very beginning of my notebook and just later determine the value of `a`. In order that the function is compilable I need to reload the package a second time after assigning a value to `a`. Is it possible that the internal code in the package automatically takes over the value of `a` without calling it a second time in the notebook environment? I tried something like `` a:=Global`a `` but it does not seem to work.

What would be the common approach to such a problem.

#### Edit

Of course, I could initialize the parameter first, before I call the package. Though I wonder whether there is a solution if I do it the other way round.

Comment: Can you show us a minimal example?

Comment: Side note: Passing information to a package via global variables somehow defeats the purpose making it a separate unit in the first place… Wouldn't something like a public variable within the package or even a "`configure[…]`" function be a better way to handle things? Of course, this alone doesn't fix the issue in the question

Comment: To give a meaningful answer, at least the outline how you defined the compiled function and where and how it uses the parameter `a` would really help. You don't need to include the whole definition of your compiled function, but it must be clear how you use the value of `a` inside your package.

Comment: Passing a variable as a global variable to a `CompiledFunction` is _a very bad idea_ because this will cause calls to the main evaluator which 1.) makes the compiled function slow and 2.) it makes parallelization of it impossible. Include `a` to the argument pattern of the compiled function and everything should work out fine.

Answer (score 4):

Are you perhaps groping toward *partial evaluation*? How about

```
generalFunc[a_]:=Compile[{b}, something containing a and b]
```

in your package. This defers compilation until you do something like:

```
specificFunc = generalFunc[2];
```

which substitutes `2` for `a` in your function and then compiles it, yielding a function only of `b`.